# DatabaseError: no such table

Tags: django, django-admin

Going insane here.

So here it goes, the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 366, in wrapper
   return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 89, in _wrapped_view_func
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 196, in inner
   return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
   return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in bound_func
   return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 224, in inner
   return func(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1274, in delete_view
   [obj], opts, request.user, self.admin_site, using)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 104, in get_deleted_objects
   collector.collect(objs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 155, in collect
   return super(NestedObjects, self).collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 175, in collect
   if not sub_objs:

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 130, in __nonzero__
   iter(self).next()

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 118, in _result_iter
   self._fill_cache()

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in _fill_cache
   self._result_cache.append(self._iter.next())

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
   for row in compiler.results_iter():

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
   for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
   cursor.execute(sql, params)

 File "/var/www/phaethon/virtualenvs/my_random_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 344, in execute
   return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

DatabaseError: no such table: orders_orderline
```

The strange thing is that this only get shown on admin view, ie:

http://www.myrandomsite.gr/admin/store/product/138/delete/

If I fire up the shell from ./manage.py shell I can call .delete() on the object just fine.

Another strange thing is, that it works fine on my local machine just fine. It only happens on the apache deployment. I have a couple of more websites that use the same stuff and work just fine.

I am mirroring apps, python version and db. I tried recreating everything, virtualenv, db, etc.

Tried ack'ing everywhere to see where that orders_orderline is defined. It's just another app in my project, that is not set in INSTALLED_APPS or anywhere. I only use it in a specific view (the model OrderLine) that is only imported if the app is installed.

edit: I sqlite3 mydb and I also can't find any reference to that table, 'cause it shouldn't exist in the first place, where is admin picking it up?

edit2: This only happens if I set DEBUG, TEMPLATE_DEBUG = FALSE

Comment: `I only use it in a specific view (the model OrderLine) that is only imported if the app is installed.` Might want to add that part to the OP.

Comment: Probably django admin trying remove the related objects. Could you try `python manage.py syncdb` or `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Already tried both of those. I can't locate where admin is picking this up, really.